# grass gis i.atcorr input should be reflectance or radiance

Tags: grass-gis

**What should be the input image in [`i.atcorr`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.atcorr.html) for grass 6.4.4 version**?

I tried giving both reflectance (DN) and radiance as input but values are coming properly.  I read some where, it internally converts to radiance and uses.

Is it like that?

If I give radiance as input, the values are not coming properly in shadow region effect is more.  So I used [`i.landsat.toar`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.landsat.toar.html) and given as input to `i.atcorr` without marking the flag *input converted to reflectance(default is radiance)*.  But the output values are not correct for flat terrain and hilly terrain (both tested)

Also one more I need to know is if I would compare the output of `i.atcorr` with surface reflectance product (from landsat website) will it be proper or not?

I have used srtm dem and atmospheric parameters from modis website.

So all the parameters are given, but is it correct way to verify our final output or any other way is there?

Answer (score 4):

## Reflectance VS Radiance

- `i.landsat.toar` derives, by default, *Spectral Reflectance* values (unitless, ranging in [0,1]), whether uncorrected or corrected (by some of the possible DOS methods).
- `i.atcorr` treats, by default, input bands as *Spectral Radiance*.

To make things work, either derive Spectral Radiance values via `i.landsat.toar` by instructing the `-r` flag, **or** let `i.atcorr` treat the input as Spectral Reflectance via its own `-r` flag and apply on-top of the input values the 6S algorithm sofisticated "correction" calculations!

## Range of values

Another pair of parameters to keep in mind, are `range` and `rescale`. The default settings are to expect an input ranging in [0,255] (`range=0,255`) and derive an output *scaled* in [0,255] (`rescale=0,255`) too!

## Remarks

Note, it is not correct to identify raw *Digital Numbers* (radiometrically corrected pixel values, or name them counts) which are unitless, with *Spectral Radiance* values, the latter expressed in *watts per steradian per square metre* (W/m<sup>2</sup>/μm/sr).

## Overview

An ascii-art flowchart on `i.landsat.toar` and `i.atcorr`:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                              |
| Digital Numbers                                                              |
|        |                                                                     |
|  +-----v-----+                                                               |
|  |  i.*.toar | ---> Reflectance                                              |
|  +-----+-----+     (uncorrected)~~~(DOS methods)--+                          |
|        |                 +                        |                          |
|    (-r flag)         (-r flag)                    +--> "Corrected"           |
|        |                 |                        |     Reflectance          |
|        v           +-----v----+                   |                          |
|     Radiance ------> i.atcorr +-------------------+                          |
|                    +----------+                                              |
|                                                                        ;-)   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```